# Trying to change static IP with a variable

Tags: powershell, static, ip

My code changes the last octet of the ip 20+, now I'm trying to set the local ip address with the variable I set but it doesn't change it:

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4").split(':')[1].trim() 
#variable that finds the IPv4 address

$octet = [byte[]]($ip -split '\.')
$octet[-1]+=20
$ip = $octet -join '.'
$ip
#Changes last octet +20

$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "Description LIKE '%Intel%'"
$wmi.EnableStatic("$ip", "255.255.255.224")
#Changes Local IP Address
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using Get-NetAdapter.

**From DHCP to Static IP:**

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4").split(':')[1].trim() 
#variable that finds the IPv4 address

$octet = [byte[]]($ip -split '\.')
$octet[-1]+=20
$ip = $octet -join '.'

$NetAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | ?{$_.InterfaceDescription -match "Intel"}
$NetAdapter | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Disabled
$NetAdapter | New-NetIPAddress -IPAddress $ip -PrefixLength 27 #27=255.255.255.224
```

**Updating Existing Static IP:**

I tried to use Set-NetIPAddress, but there appears to be a bug with that.  A quick search showed others having issues with Set-NetIPAddress as well.  So below I just removed the IP then added the new one.

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4").split(':')[1].trim() 
#variable that finds the IPv4 address

$octet = [byte[]]($ip -split '\.')
$octet[-1]+=20
$ip = $octet -join '.'

$NetAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | ? {$_.InterfaceDescription -match "Intel"}
$NetAdapter | Remove-NetIPAddress -confirm:$false
$NetAdapter | New-NetIPAddress -ipaddress $ip -PrefixLength "27"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not getting the results you expect from your WMI query and are setting some virtual interface, or failing to set an interface that's not settable, or failing to set anything at all if your query returns a collection.

To see what the query is returning, add `$wmi | fl *` at the very end. Is it a single interface, and is it the one you thought you were getting? My guess would be that the answer is no.

Are you seeing any error messages? A mistake that I see you're making twice is assuming a single result when multiple results are possible.

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4").split(':')[1].trim()
```

This line will result in an error unless your IP configuration has one and only one line with an "IPv4", resulting in a string. If there are multiple matches, you'll get an array, and if there are no matches, you'll get **$null**. Either way, when you try to invoke the **Split** method, you'll get an error saying either that the object doesn't have a **Split** method or that you can't invoke a method on a null-valued expression. So this may be working for you, but it's not reliable.

This might work if you're sure you'll always want the first result...

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4")[0].split(':')[1].trim()
```

or (longer but clearer)

```
$ip = (ipconfig | findstr "IPv4" | select -First 1).split(':')[1].trim()
```

...but it would be a better idea to use a more specific way of finding the address you're looking to change.

Similarly, the following line could return a single object, or an array:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -filter "Description LIKE '%Intel%'"
```

If more than one interface matches the filter (which isn't too unlikely, considering that it's common to have a plethora of virtual interfaces), you'll get an error when you try to invoke **EnableStatic**. Again, you can tack `| select -First 1` to the end, or enclose everything to the right of the `=` in `( )[0]`. However, to make it more likely that you'll get a single result for your primary interface, try this:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "Description LIKE '%Intel%' AND IPEnabled = 'True'"
```